# File gets overwritten when writing to file using write()

Tags: c, file

I am trying to log my signals that are recieved by my process. Whenever i write to the `signal.log` file, it just gets over written. Am I missing a file flag for appending by chance or something?

Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "signalinfo.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


void 
setsig(struct sigaction sa)
{    

int i;

for(i=0; i<SIGNAL_LIST_LENGTH; i++) {
    if(sigaction(siglist[i].code, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        printf("Sigaction Error When: %s \n", siglist[i].name);
        }           
    }

}

void 
handler(int sig)
{
    char path[PATH_MAX];
    int fd, flags, i;

    flags = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IWOTH | S_IROTH;
    getcwd(path, PATH_MAX);
    strcat(path,"/signal.log");
    fd = open(path, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_NONBLOCK, flags);


    for(i=0; i<SIGNAL_LIST_LENGTH; i++) {
        if(sig == siglist[i].code) {
            write(fd, siglist[i].name, strlen(siglist[i].name));
        }
    }

     close(fd);

}

    int
    main(void)
    {   
        struct sigaction sa;
        sa.sa_handler = handler;

        setsig(sa);

        while(1) {
            printf("In loop with PID: %d\n", getpid());
            sleep(1);
        }
     }
```

Is this happening by chance because I am missing a flag? After running it, the file is not appended and only one line is written

```
  SIGINT
```

I am using write as it is a async-signal-safe function

Comment: Wont `O_TRUNC` truncate the file on opening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the append flag

```
O_APPEND
```

and remove

```
O_TRUNC
```

Comment: I added it to the flags section and it did not append the file. It is still only printing one line in the file.

Comment: Ah sorry I missed this. You need to remove the truncate flag